# remove document from all collection based on a condition

Tags: mongodb

I would like to delete few documents from all collections using the same purge condition. i.e suppose i have three collections test,test1 & test2. all these collections have common column "ZIP", now I want to delete from above three collections based on some zip code.

Comment: Which language is this? What would be so difficult about running three requests to remove them? Why do you have data in three collections to start with? Also https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+remove+document+from+collection shows you a lot of useful details and there does not seem to be any attempt at doing anything within the question. If you have a specific reason to ask then you should be explaining that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to execute individual `remove()` calls but you can reuse the condition like this:

```
var condition = { "ZIP": 12345 }
db.collection1.remove(condition)
db.collection2.remove(condition)
db.collection3.remove(condition)
```

In order to process literally each an every collection - that includes system collections, too - and views you can do this:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(col) { db[col].remove(condition) })
```

Comment: A couple of suggestions: 1) You can use `db.getCollectionNames().forEach(col => db[col].remove(...))` to iterate through all collections. 2) Use `deleteMany()` instead of `remove()` to make it clear you're removing many documents from each collection.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha: Yeah, thanks, fair points. I was assuming that "all collections" in the context of the question might not necessarily mean "all". ;)

Comment: @KevinAdistambha it tried but didn't work in my case. can you please clarify it?

Comment: Which language/driver/client are you using?

Comment: running directly on mongo shell, need to automate it on an ubuntu system.